# Kivy how to use Builder.load_file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
    controller/
        __init__.py
        app1.py
    view/
        app1.kv
    main.py
```

My `main.py`is:

```
from controller.app1 import App1


def main():
    App1().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My `app1.py`is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('view/app1.kv')

class App1(App):
    pass
```

I am running:

```
kivy main.py
```

However, the contents of my Kivy is not loaded.

Comment: Try `Builder.load_file(os.path.join(dirname(__file__), '../view/app1.kv'))`

Comment: @Leon, I am now getting am error that says that the file does not exist.

Comment: Does it report the file path? Is it a correct path or not?

Comment: It is not the correct path to that file. I am getting this `/Users/user/folder/kivy_spikes/controller/view/app1.kv` which is not the path to the file.

Comment: Note that I have edited my original comment (added `../` to the path)

Comment: @Leon, yeah though I fixed that, but it is still not loading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135106/discussion-between-leon-and-lmiguelvargasf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the method `build()` has to be implemented in the class that inherits from `App` and this method has to return `Builder.load_file('view/app1.kv')`, and using @Leon suggestion my `app1.py` is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file(
        os.path.join(dirname(__file__), '../view/app1.kv')
    )
```

Now, the Kivy file is properly loaded.

Answer (score 3):

When you load a .kv file using `Build.load_file` make sure the widget is the `root`
to avoid it from returning None.read the [doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html) to see other things you do with Builder

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file(os.path.join(dirname(__file__),/app1.kv')
    )
```