# Integration of multiple .kv files

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

As I am learning kivy/kivymd these days, my questions might be naive, please pardon me for that. I want to create multiple screens in kivy and the definition of each screen to be placed in separate .kv file. At last, I'm creating a main.kv file which has ScreenManager definition and I want to import all the screens defined to this app. Please guide me on how to do this.

Here is my screen1.kv file

```
<Screen1>:
    name: 'Screen1'
    Label:
        id: first_screen
        text: "Hi I'm The First Screen"
```

Here is my screen2.kv file

```
<Screen2>:
    name: 'Screen2'
    Label:
        id: second_screen
        text: "Hi I'm The Second Screen"
```

Here is my main.kv file

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:include libs.kv.screen1.kv
#:include libs.kv.screen2.kv

ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: "main_screen"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Label:
                text: "main screen"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 1"
                on_press: app.root.current = "Screen1"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 2"
                on_press: app.root.current = "Screen2"
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
```

Please guide on what is the correct way to write main.kv as I'm getting error. Please note, I want to eliminate the python code of ScreenManager.add_widget(Screen1....)

Comment: would this help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-use-multiple-kv-files-in-kivy/   ?

Comment: Hi @n4321d I saw this gfg post, but the difference here is it assumes all the files are at same location. My files are at diff location than main.kv. It's something like this

Comment: I understand, Builder.load_file accepts the full file path so you can do: Builder.load_file("/myAPP/screen2/screen2.kv"), Builder.load_file("/myAPP/screen3/screen3.kv") ... etc. If you have a list with all your file paths you can use a list comprehension such as: [Builder.load_file(f) for f in file_list]; more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097197/kivy-how-to-use-builder-load-file

Comment: How those `kv` files get imported is entirely dependent on where they are located, but you have not provided that information.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `#:include libs/kv/screen1.kv`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson this worked. Thanks a lot for that. When you work in python you forget that, '/' can also be used for defining destination path.

Comment: By using '/' I can include the screens in .kv file but unable to use the functions defined for particular widget in .py file

For example, if there is function called show_data() in class Screen1 defined in screen1.py file, the same function can't be used in .kv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create multiple screens defined in different .py files and their .kv definition in separate files. In order to integrate all the files, we can create a main.kv file whose content looks like below:

```
#  import the python files defining the Screens
#: import Screen1 libs.baseclass.screen1.Screen1
#: import Screen2 libs.baseclass.screen2.Screen2

#  include the kv files for the other Screens
#: include libs/kvs/screen1.kv
#: include libs/kvs/screen2.kv

ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
```

FInally load this file through Builder in an App.